# Google Script trigger on form submit not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, eventtrigger

I am trying to make the function run using the trigger onFormResponse. However, when I am testing with live form, nothing happens. I have tried deleting, recreating both trigger and the script, but it still does not work. Thank you for your help!

```
   function onSubmit(e) {

  //function get ID of the submitted response, log it to the console
  //run a afunction that ask for permission to get a refilled URL 
  //based on the submitted one
  //email the log to me


  //get current form
  var currentForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  // Get ID of form on submited
  var ID = e.response.getId();
  Logger.log(ID);


  checkPermission(currentResponse);

  var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var subject = 'Log';
  var body = Logger.getLog();
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
  Logger.clear();

}
function checkPermission(e){
  var ui = FormApp.getUi();
  var dialogBox = ui.alert('Do you want to create a prefill form?',
                           FormApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  if(dialogBox == ui.Botton.YES){
    var link = ui.alert(e.toPrefilledUrl());
  }

}

function triggerTester(){
  // create a an on form submit trigger for function onSubmit
  var currentForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onSubmit')
     .forForm(currentForm)
     .onFormSubmit().create();
}
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is VIEW the EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT.  At the bottom of the Log print out, there should be a statement about whether the script completed or not, and if not, what line the error occurred on.

Comment: This is a script in the Form or in the receiving spreadsheet?

Comment: @Karl_S This script is solely for the form

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to comment but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation:

I would use this solution:

```
function onSubmitTrigger(){
 //psuedocode(ish)
       /*
1.Get range of values
2.Find last submitted value
3.Pass value to function "onSubmit"
    */        
}
  function onSubmit(e) {

  //function get ID of the submitted response, log it to the console
  //run a afunction that ask for permission to get a refilled URL 
  //based on the submitted one
  //email the log to me


  //get current form
  var currentForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  // Get ID of form on submited
  var ID = e.response.getId();
  Logger.log(ID);


  checkPermission(currentResponse);

  var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var subject = 'Log';
  var body = Logger.getLog();
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
  Logger.clear();

}
function checkPermission(e){
  var ui = FormApp.getUi();
  var dialogBox = ui.alert('Do you want to create a prefill form?',
                           FormApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  if(dialogBox == ui.Botton.YES){
    var link = ui.alert(e.toPrefilledUrl());
  }

}

function triggerTester(){
  // create a an on form submit trigger for function onSubmit
  var currentForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onSubmit')
     .forForm(currentForm)
     .onFormSubmit().create();
}
```

You can set the trigger within the actual service:
Click on the clock icon:
[image: Clock Icon]

Then go ahead and set up a new trigger:
[image: Set up]

Select the function `onSubmitTrigger()` and you can set it up to run as the form is submitted:
[image: Set-Up]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I found out that the problem was actually from the Ui function in form editor vs despondence.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the Ui functions cannot be applied to form response, but only to the editor, while I am trying to add a "pop-up" dialog box to check permission. Currently there is not a work around for creating a pop-up dialog box for Google form response.